# How to upgrade ngx_pagespeed in production server?

Tags: centos, nginx, lamp, mod-pagespeed

I have a LEMP set-up in CentOS 7. I am planning to install the ngx_pagespeed module to it. When I was reading through the docs I came to realise that unlike Apache, I cannot install this module dynamically with Nginx. So from my understanding, I now need to uninstall the current Nginx, compile Nginx with ngx_pagespeed and re-install this compiled version. This comes to my next question: **What happens if I have to upgrade Nginx or ngx_pagespeed module in the future and I already have a working production LEMP server with ngx_pagespeed?** Do I then need to do the same i.e uninstall Nginx + ngx_pagespeed first, compile the latest version of the module & nginx and reinstall the newer version? It seems to be a big hassle. Isint there a better or simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will have to rebuild nginx with pagespeed but once you got your RPM spec it's not that long. You can find one [here](https://github.com/ubc/nginx-pagespeed-rpm).

You can upgrade between two nginx versions **without any downtime** with `USR2` and `WINCH` signals so master processes using the new binary are spawn while you gracefully shutdown the old ones.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your answer @Xavier. I wasnt aware of Nginx + pagespeed RPM as well as USR2 and WINCH until you mentioned. I am a newbie to server adm and your pointers have helped a lot. I read the tutorial in rosehosting and I thought I need to do all those steps each time I upgrade. Now your reply has put me to ease a bit since it does make it simple enough. Thanks heaps... :)